# What is a designated initializer in C?

Tags: c, struct, unions, initializer, designated-initializer

I have an assignment that requires me to understand what are **designated initializers** in C, and what it means to initialize a variable with one.

I am not familiar with the term and couldn't find any conclusive definitions.

**What is a designated initializer in C?**

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251698/discussion-on-question-by-user7349461-what-is-a-designated-initializer-in-c); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Designated initialisers come in two flavours:

1) It provides a quick way of initialising specific elements in an array:

```
int foo[10] = { [3] = 1, [5] = 2 };
```

will set all elements to `foo` to 0, other than index 3 which will be set to 1 and index 5 which will be set to 2.

2) It provides a way of explicitly initialising `struct` members. For example, for

```
struct Foo { int a, b; };
```

you can write

```
struct Foo foo { .a = 1, .b = 2 };
```

Note that in this case, members that are not explicitly initialised are initialised as if the instance had `static` duration.

---

Both are standard C, but note that C++ does not support either (as constructors can do the job in that language.)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0329r4.pdf) for further reading about C++. I believe it's well set for the next standard.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Need to dig out my standard for my final comment before the ruled line. (Alas I'm on the choo choo). I *think* it's correct.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p9 at least unnamed structure members are uninitialized.

Comment: The members (of the variable) that are not explicitly initialized in the code will be automatically initialized by the compiler to 0. Much like all static and global variables are always automatically initialized to 0 when not done explicitly in the code.

Comment: In  struct Foo foo { .a = ...  should there be an equal sign like this: struct Foo foo = { .a = ...

Answer (score 24):

The Designated Initializer came up since the ISO C99 and is a different and more dynamic way to initialize in C when initializing `struct`, `union` or an `array`.

The biggest difference to standard initialization is that you don't have to declare the elements in a fixed order and you can also omit element.

From The [GNU Guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html):

> Standard C90 requires the elements of an initializer to appear in a fixed order, the same as the order of the elements in the array or structure being initialized.

> In ISO C99 you can give the elements in random order, specifying the array indices or structure field names they apply to, and GNU C allows this as an extension in C90 mode as well

---

### Examples

#### 1. Array Index

**Standard Initialization**

```c
  int a[6] = { 0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0 };
```

**Designated Initialization**

```c
  int a[6] = {[4] = 29, [2] = 15 }; // or
  int a[6] = {[4]29 , [2]15 }; // or
  int widths[] = { [0 ... 9] = 1, [10 ... 99] = 2, [100] = 3 };
```

#### 2. Struct or union:

**Standard Initialization**

```c
struct point { int x, y; };
```

**Designated Initialization**

```c
 struct point p = { .y = 2, .x = 3 }; or
 struct point p = { y: 2, x: 3 };
```

#### 3. Combine naming elements with ordinary C initialization of successive elements:

**Standard Initialization**

```c
int a[6] = { 0, v1, v2, 0, v4, 0 };
```

**Designated Initialization**

```c
int a[6] = { [1] = v1, v2, [4] = v4 };
```

#### 4. Others:

**Labelling the elements of an array initializer**

```c
int whitespace[256] = { [' '] = 1, ['\t'] = 1, ['\h'] = 1,
                        ['\f'] = 1, ['\n'] = 1, ['\r'] = 1 };
```

**write a series of ‘.fieldname’ and ‘[index]’ designators before an ‘=’ to specify a nested subobject to initialize**

```c
struct point ptarray[10] = { [2].y = yv2, [2].x = xv2, [0].x = xv0 };
```

---

### Guides

- [designated-initializers-c | geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/designated-initializers-c/)
- [using-designated-initializers](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/18609/using-designated-initializers)
- [tutorialspoint.com | designated-initializers-in-c](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/designated-initializers-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

**C99 standard draft**

This is not going to be particularly enlightening, but just to satisfy my own morbid curiosity: [WG14/N1256 C99 standard draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> 6.7.8 Initialization
>
> ```
> designator-list:
>   designator
>   designator-list designator
>
> designator:
>   [ constant-expression ]
>   . identifier
> ```
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 6 If a designator has the form
>
> ```
> [ constant-expression ]
> ```
>
> then the current object (defined below) shall have array type and the expression shall be
> an integer constant expression. If the array is of unknown size, any nonnegative value is
> valid.
>
> 7 If a designator has the form
>
> ```
> . identifier
> ```
>
> then the current object (defined below) shall have structure or union type and the
> identifier shall be the name of a member of that type.
>
> **Semantics**
>
> 17 Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no
> designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
> to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure
> members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.129) In contrast, a
> designation causes the following initializer to begin initialization of the subobject
> described by the designator. Initialization then continues forward in order, beginning
> with the next subobject after that described by the designator
>
> 18 Each designator list begins its description with the current object associated with the
> closest surrounding brace pair. Each item in the designator list (in order) specifies a
> particular member of its current object and changes the current object for the next
> designator (if any) to be that member.131) The current object that results at the end of the
> designator list is the subobject to be initialized by the following initializer.
>
> EXAMPLE 9 Arrays can be initialized to correspond to the elements of an enumeration by using designators:
>
> ```
> enum { member_one, member_two };
> const char *nm[] = {
>     [member_two] = "member two",
>     [member_one] = "member one",
> }
> ```
>
> EXAMPLE 11 Designators can be used to provide explicit initialization when unadorned initializer lists
> might be misunderstood:
>
> ```
> struct { int a[3], b; } w[] =
>     { [0].a = {1}, [1].a[0] = 2 };
> ```