# C double parentheses

Tags: c, function-pointers, declaration, ctor-initializer

I don't know what this "feature" is called so I coudn't google it also I'm sorry if the title doesn't make sense. I recently looked at suckless dwm's source and saw this code: (from dwm.c)

```
static int (*xerrorxlib)(Display *, XErrorEvent *);
```

And also this:

```
static void (*handler[LASTEvent]) (XEvent *) = {
    [ButtonPress] = buttonpress,
    [ClientMessage] = clientmessage,
    [ConfigureRequest] = configurerequest,
    [ConfigureNotify] = configurenotify,
    [DestroyNotify] = destroynotify,
    [EnterNotify] = enternotify,
    [Expose] = expose,
    [FocusIn] = focusin,
    [KeyPress] = keypress,
    [KeyRelease] = keypress,
    [MappingNotify] = mappingnotify,
    [MapRequest] = maprequest,
    [MotionNotify] = motionnotify,
    [PropertyNotify] = propertynotify,
    [UnmapNotify] = unmapnotify
};
```

What does `void (*handler[LASTEvent]) (XEvent *)` mean ? What it is called and why it is used for ?

Comment: The first thing is a pointer to a function.  The second is a "[designated initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202557)", I think.

Comment: https://www.cdecl.org

Comment: https://goshdarnfunctionpointers.com/

Comment: I learned what I was looking for, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This declaration

```
static int (*xerrorxlib)(Display *, XErrorEvent *);
```

is a declaration of a pointer to function with the name `xerrorxlib` that ( the function)  has the return type `int` and two parameters of pointer types `Display *` and `XErrorEvent *`.

The pointer has the static storage duration.

This declaration

```
static void (*handler[LASTEvent]) (XEvent *) = {
```

declares an array with the name `handler` of `LASTEvent` elements of pointers to function with the return type `void` and the parameter type `XEvent *`. The array also has the static storage duration.

As for records like this

```
[ButtonPress] = buttonpress,
```

then in the square brackets there is an index of the array element that is initialized.

For example you can write

```
enum { First = 0, Second = 1 };
```

and then to use the enumerators in the braced init list in an array declaration like

```
int a[] =
{
    [First] = 10,
    [Second] = 20
};
```

In this case the array will have two elements where the element with the index 0 is initialized by the value 10 and the element with the index 1 is initialized with the value 20.

Comment: So if I didn't get it wrong, it is mapping the LASTEvent to functions, where LASTEvent is the parameter used to index other functions, but what is [ButtonPress], [ClientMessage] and other things inside square brackets ? Why are they like { [ButtonPress] = buttonpress, [ClientMessage] = clientmessage } and not just a the name of the functions like { buttonpress, clientmessage ...} What are the things inside square brackets ?

Comment: @Zer0day LASTEvent is the number of elements in the declared array.  As for elements like [ButtonPress] then in the square brackets there are specified indices of the array that probably were declared as enumerators.