# Multiple values in MACRO

Tags: c, macros

Could I find help dissecting this macro. The syntax seems familiar yet strange.

```c
#define   MACRO_NAME   [0] = value0, [1] = value1, [2] = value3
```

It's a macro I came across while maintaining code.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not macro syntax. `MACRO_NAME` will be replaced by `[0] = value0, [1] = value1, [2] = value3`, literally. This syntax has nothing to do with the preprocessor.

Comment: The notation could be for designated initialization of an array.  It's clumsy to use, though.  `#define value0 37` … `int array[] = { MACRO_NAME };`

Comment: Notably it would have been better to include the braces in the macro too, for macro safety reasons. Apart from that, making macros for array initializer lists isn't uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple macro. The preprocessor will replace any occurrence of `MACRO_NAME` with `[0] = value0, [1] = value1, [2] = value3`.

Thus, the macro seems to have a purpose in [designated initialization of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202557/what-is-a-designated-initializer-in-c), however, its usefulness is difficult to imagine. It requires that `value0`, `value1`, and `value3` are defined (either as variables or macros) at the place where `MACRO_NAME` is expanded.

E.g.:

```
   #define value0 12
   #define value1 17
   int value3 = 24;
   int a[4] = {MACRO_NAME, [3] = 100};
   int b[5] = {MACRO_NAME, [3] = 200, [4] = 11};
```

Comment: In other words: it's a terrible abuse of macros that only causes confusion..

Comment: @Jabberwocky It is not, it is confusion caused by insufficient language knowledge.